# Why is my image not resizing when other attributes are working fine?

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I have been trying to resize this image in the following code. I have tried px, em, % and leaving the unit type blank but it will not resize. I have tried both width and height but neither make it change.
The other attributes in the CSS are working fine: margin, position etc.
Why won't the image resize?

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this and for your suggestion.

### Code below

The HTML

```
    <div id='fixed-button'>

        <a href='main-home-timeline.html'>
          <img src='images/im-lost-clock.png'>
        </a>

        </div>

The CSS

    #fixed-button {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS is targeting the div, not the image. Values must always have a  unit suffix. If you want the image to be the width of the parent, use `width: 100%` - on the image

Comment: got to always check for this... targeting div here won't make it assume you want the img changed you must tell it to

Comment: _"Values must always have a unit suffix"_ - unless the value is zero.

Comment: Is my answer also correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put width and/or height attributes for the img element, i.e. either you define a class for the img and then put width: 10px in it, or use the selector `#fixed-button a img`

```
#fixed-button a img {
    width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image needs to be `width: 100%;` if you plan to change the parent, so it can follow it. Or explicitly change image width with:

```
#fixed-button img {
 width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the `Width`property to 100px so that you can solve the current problem.

```
#fixed-button {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 600px;
}
```

Hope that this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You are resizing the div element not the image element. The correct code is given below.

CSS

```
.fixed-button {
position: fixed;
width: 10px;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 120px;
margin-left: 600px;
}
.img1 {
position: fixed;
width: 10px;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 120px;
margin-left: 600px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="fixed-button" class="fixed-button">
<a href="main-home-timeline.html">
<img src="images/im-lost-clock.png" id="img1" class="img1" />
</a>
</div>
```